# Activity Schedule (Gantt Diagram)

Tags: tables, calendar

Does anyone knows how to do an activity schedule like this?

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  There are quite some packages that are dedicated to producing gantt charts. A search at CTAN reveals this list: https://ctan.org/topic/gantt For some code example, you may also want to take a look at questions ans answers that are tagged [gantt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gantt)  or [pgfgantt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pgfgantt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [pgfgantt](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfgantt), which I find quite easy to use.